# Customer latency in r

Tags: r

New to R doing customer latency.

- In the dataset i have around 300,000 rows with 15 columns. Some
  relevant columns are "**Account**", "**Account Open Date**",
  "**Shipment pick up date**" etc.
- Account numbers are repeated and just want the rows with account numbers where it is recorded for the first time, not the subsequent rows.

  For eg. acc # 610829952 is in the first row as well as in the 5th row, 6th row etc. I need to filter out the first row alone and i need to do this for all the account numbers.

I am not sure how to do this. Could someone please help me with this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried already? Please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in `R` called `duplicated()`. It allows you to check whether a certain value, like your `account`, has already been recorded.

First you check in the relevant column `account` which account numbers have already appeared before using `duplicated()`. You will get a `TRUE / FALSE` vector (`TRUE` indicating that the corresponding value has already appeared). With that information, you will index your data.frame in order to only retrieve the rows you are interested in. I will assume you have your data looks like `df` below:

```
df <- data.frame(segment = sample(LETTERS, 20, replace = TRUE),
                 account = sample(1:5, 20, replace = TRUE))
#      account segment
# 1        3       N
# 2        2       V
# 3        4       T
# 4        4       Y
# 5        4       M
# 6        4       E
# 7        5       H
# 8        3       A
# 9        3       J
# 10       3       Y
# 11       4       R
# 12       5       O
# 13       4       O
# 14       1       R
# 15       5       U
# 16       2       Q
# 17       5       F
# 18       2       J
# 19       4       E
# 20       2       H

inds <- duplicated(df$account)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
# [11]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
df <- df[!inds, ]
#     account   segment
# 1        3       N
# 2        2       V
# 3        4       T
# 7        5       H
# 14       1       R
```